# how to send data with ever $http post

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

I wanted to be able to send `ipAddress` for every $http.post() that's being sent to backend without manually mentioning it every time i send a post. How to do it in angular ? I found out there was `$ajax.setup` in jQuery could you please provide me with an example for doing something similar in angular js?

```
$http.post('actions.php', {ip: ipAddress, data: add})
        .then(function (response) {
            alert("post sent")
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your `ipAddress` in HTTP headers in a runtime like this:

```
module.run(function($http) {
  $http.defaults.headers.common.IpAddress = ipAddress;
});
```

or add it to HTTP headers to all requests,these defaults can be fully configured by accessing the `$httpProvider.defaults.headers` configuration object, which currently contains this default configuration.

For more info check the `Setting HTTP Headers` section of `$http` service on [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom "$http" factory that add your custom data to every request.

```
angular.module('app', [])
.factory('myHttp', ['$http', function($http)
{
    return function(method, url, args)
    {
        var data = angular.extend({ip: '127.0.0.1'}, args);

        return $http[method](url, data);
    };
}])
.controller('myCtrl', function($http, myHttp)
{
    myHttp('post', 'actions.php', {a: 'a'})
        .then(function(response)
        {
            alert("post send");
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $http interceptors. You can add your interceptor to $httpProvider. It will be called for every $http request. You can add your logic to request method of your interceptor. See some usages [here](http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

this will work.First capture the ip address of the client using get method then send it using post method.

```
 <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $http) {
            var json = 'http://ipv4.myexternalip.com/json';
            $http.get(json).then(function(result) {
                var ip_addr=result.data.ip;
                var config = {
                    headers : {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
                    }
                }
                $http.post('actions.php', ip_addr, config)
                    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.PostDataResponse = data;
                })
                console.log(ip_addr);
            }, function(e) {
                alert("error");
            });
        });

    </script>
```